# Assume that $g\in C(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})\cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$. Prove that there is only one solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Assume that $g\in C(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})\cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})$. Then construct a function $u$ satisfying

1. $u\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}_+^n)\cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R}_+^n)\cap C(\overline{\mathbb{R}_+^n})$
2. $\Delta u=0$ in $\mathbb{R}_+^n$
3. $u(x',0)=g(x')$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$

Use the results Liouville's Theorem and

> 1. Let $U^+$ denote the open half-ball $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n
>         \hspace{0.25cm} | \hspace{0.25cm} |x|<1, x_n>0\}$. Assume $u\in
>         C^2(\overline{U^+})$ is harmonic in $U^+$, with $u=0$ on $\partial
>         U^+ \cap \{x_n=0\}$. Set [ v(x):=\begin{cases} u(x) & \text{ if }
>         x_n\geq 0 \\
>         -u(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},-x_n) & \text{ if } x_n < 0 \end{cases} ] for $x\in U=B^0(0,1)$. Prove $v\in C^2(U)$ and thus $v$ is harmonic
>       within $U$.
> 2. Now assume only that $u\in C^2(U^+)\cap C(\overline{U^+})$. Show
>       that $v$ is harmonic within $U$.

to prove that there is only one such solution (that is there is just one bounded solution.)

Note here $\overline{\mathbb{R}_+^n}=\{(x',x_n):x'\in\mathbb{R}^{n-1} \text{ and } x_n\geq 0\}$.

**So is my thinking correct?**
From the result that is in the blockquote we get that $u$ is harmonic. And to apply Liousville's Theorem, I need to show that $u$ is bounded. Once I do that I am done.

**How?** How would I prove that $u$ is bounded based off the information I have? Also it says "only one" do I have to show unqiueness? If so, how?

Comment: Your construction of $u$ via the Green's function will establish that $u$ is bounded (it's a weighted average of $g$, which is bounded). To show uniqueness, take the difference of two solutions, and show that after extending to the whole plane, this difference is a bounded harmonic function, and hence identically zero by Liouville.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the part of "how that after extending to the whole plane, this difference is a bounded harmonic function"?

Comment: Use the facts you put in the block, and the fact that $u$ is bounded.